# Passing an object between states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I have been trying to pass the object clicked in template page1 to another template called page2 using angular.  I am able to access this object using ng-click but I am not able to pass it to the other template.  I have read using state.go() might work, but I have not been able to figure this out.  If state.go() isn't a good idea what should I use instead?

```js
angular.module('playground', [])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  "use strict";

  /* Set up the states for the application's different sections. */
  $stateProvider
    .state('page1', {
      name: 'page1',
      url: '/page1',
      templateUrl: 'page1.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .state('page2', {
      name: 'page2',
      url: '/page2',
      templateUrl: 'page2.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page1');

})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
  "use strict";


  $scope.add = function(item, $stateParams) {
    if ($scope.ordered.indexOf(item) > -1) {

      //nothing for now

    } else {

      $scope.ordered.push(item);

    }

    console.log($scope.ordered);
  };

  $scope.ordered = []

  $scope.menu = [{
    title: 'Pizza',
    type: 'entree',
    favorite: true,
    price: 10
  }, {
    title: 'Tacos',
    type: 'entree',
    favorite: false,
    price: 5
  }, {
    title: 'Onion Rings',
    type: 'app',
    favorite: false,
    price: 2
  }, {
    title: 'Ice Cream',
    type: 'dessert',
    favorite: false,
    price: 11
  }, {
    title: 'Mac n Cheese',
    type: 'app',
    favorite: false,
    price: 7
  }, {
    title: 'Salad',
    type: 'salad',
    favorite: true,
    price: 4
  }];


  $scope.ordered = [];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="playground" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <script id="page1.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <div ng-repeat="item in menu">

      <p>{{item.title}}</p>

      <p>{{item.type}}</p>
      <button ng-click="add(item);">add</button>

    </div>
  </script>

  <script id="page2.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <div ng-repeat="item in ordered">

      <p>{{item.title}}</p>

      <p>{{item.type}}</p>
      <button>remove</button>

    </div>
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to share data, you can use angular service, because all angular services are **singletons**, so you can easily share data between controllers and states.

For example :

**Controller 1**

```
(() => {

  function Controller1($scope, Service) {

    $scope.test = 'In Controller 1';

    $scope.service = Service;

    $scope.menu = [
      {
      title: 'Pizza',
      type: 'entree',
      favorite: true,
      price: 10
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Tacos',
        type: 'entree',
        favorite: false,
        price: 5
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Onion Rings',
        type: 'app',
        favorite: false,
        price: 2
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Ice Cream',
        type: 'dessert',
        favorite: false,
        price: 11
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Mac n Cheese',
        type: 'app',
        favorite: false,
        price: 7
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Salad',
        type: 'salad',
        favorite: true,
        price: 4
      }
    ];

    setTimeout(() => {
      //Assign our data to the data service
      Service.data = $scope.menu;
      //Update the bindings
      $scope.$apply();
    }, 1000);


  }

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('Ctrl1', Controller1);

})();
```

**Controller 2**

```
(() => {

  function Controller2($scope, Service) {

    $scope.test = 'In Controller 2';

    //Retrieve instance of our data Service
    $scope.service = Service;

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('Ctrl2', Controller2);

})();
```

**Service**

```
(() => {

  function Service() {

    const obj = {
      data: ''
    };

    return obj;

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Service', Service);

})();
```

**Html**

```
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
      {{test}}
      <pre>{{menu | json}}</pre>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller='Ctrl2'>
      {{test}}
      <pre>{{service.data | json}}</pre>
    </div>

  </body>
```

In this example, we are passing data from controller 1 to controller 2 by using a data service. You can do the same with your states.

You can see the [**Working Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/jATw1eFBkJRisvWt2eZg?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for the help Paul, but I can't seem to get it to work. I see you're using (() =>  a lot in your code. What is that referencing? When I try this it tells me Service is an unknown service provider.

Comment: It's just the ES6 syntax for the anonymous function. In general, it's a good practice to wrap your module declaration into an anonymous function in order to isolate it from other code on the page.

You can replace this syntax by the traditional `(function(){/**/})()`.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using `$stateParams` service of Angularjs to achieve this. In your router js file where you define the routing for each state you need to define 1 more parameter "params" as below:

```
.state('state1', {
    url: "/state1",
    templateUrl: 'modules/states/state1.html',
    controller: 'state1Controller',
    controllerAs: 'state1Vm',
    params: { 'stateVals': '' }
})
```

Same way, define this params for state2 as well where you want to navigate from state1 and back.

Now before navigating from state1 to state2 you can set the object you want to access in state2 as below:

```
        state1Vm.selectedVals = {
            "key1": state1Vm.content,
            "key2": state1Vm.userInputs
        }

        $state.go('state2', { stateVals: state1Vm.selectedVals });
```

On reaching state2 you can get this object in controller of state2 as below:

```
        state2Vm.selectedVals = {
            "key1": $stateParams.stateVals.key1,
            "key2": $stateParams.stateVals.key2
        };
```

Please note that you need to inject `$stateParams` in both your controllers.